# What should I use in mongoose for csv export

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am confused whether I should use mongoose stream query of regular query. 
I have to export a csv directly from db containing aroung 1000000 records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not? use stream and output it to wherever you want, for example:

```
var stream = model.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                // query...
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                _id     : 0,
                field   : 1
            }
        }
    ]).cursor({ batchSize: 5000 }).exec().stream();

stream.on('data', function (doc) {
    // do whatever you want with the data
}).on('error', function (err) {
    // handle errors
}).on('end', function () {
    // close files
});
```

Comment: var stream = Sfb.find({process_id:processid}).stream();      what should be the fastest query for this...???

Comment: of course you can use `find` as well which is faster: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#querystream_QueryStream